# Method call inside Runnable not getting covered in Junit test android

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm trying to add unit test for my application and every thing going well expect one thing that when i have a method called after delay inside a runnable

The test passed but when i see the coverage report it show me that this method call not covered

Here is the code inside my presenter

```
  view.changeLogo();
    handler=new Handler();
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.navigateToLogIn();
        }
    },5000);
```

and here is the code inside my test

```
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            verify(view).navigateToLogIn();
        }
    },5000);
```

the only way when i can make it work when i use Thread.sleep but here i don't want to block the UI thread

Any help

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are using the real scheduling mechanism of the system. Therefore you simply have to use Thread.sleep to let the system run the other thread executing your runnable. On the other hand the systems scheduling mechanism is tested well, so you only need to test your runnable. Make your `Runnable` a class of its own which you can instantiate and test the `run` method directly.